# My reactive variable won't update (apollo client)

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

EDIT: after further investigation, now I know that reactive variables are not persistent. So that's why when the page is refreshed its value resets to the default!

I'm trying to store the logged user into a reactive variable so I can access to it in several components in my app but it always returns the default value.
This is my cache inside my Apollo Client config file:

```js
interface MeInterface {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
}

export const meVar = makeVar<MeInterface | undefined>(undefined);

cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            me: {
              read() {
                return meVar();
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
```

And then inside a button I set the values just for testing (the console log do prints the variable with the new values):

```js
const client = useReactiveVar(meVar)
<Button
  onClick={() => {
      meVar({
        id: 62,
        username: "jos",
        email: "jos",
      });
      console.log(client);
   }}
/>
```

I'm also writing the cache like so:

```js
const response = await login({
            variables: values,
            update: (cache, { data }) => {
              cache.writeQuery({
                query: MeDocument,
                data: {
                  __typename: "Query",
                  me: data?.login.user,
                },
              });
              meVar(data!.login.user);
            },
          });
```

But when I want to print the reactive variable inside a functional component in other file I get an undefined (the default value):

```js
const dd = useReactiveVar(meVar);
console.log(dd);
```

What am I doing wrong?